# How to give file,Folder and registry permissions in windows 7 on the basis of SID?

Tags: windows-7

I want to use SID for folder permission, not the group names. Please suggest with command lines or any script.

Comment: I don't believe this to be possible.  I am only aware of commands that add either the user or group to the security information of a file or folder.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Unfortunately, we are not a code-writing service. Instead of simply asking for code to perform a particular task, please show us what you've tried so far (including any code you currently have) and where you're stuck so that we can help you with your specific problem. Questions that only ask for code are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://superuser.com/help/closed-questions).

Comment: @DragonLord: Questions "asking for code" are legion here, and are most often answered without comment. Not saying that's how it should be.

Answer (score 2):

The [icacls](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc753525.aspx) command allows numerical SIDs to be used. The SID must be preceded by an asterisk (*).

Example:

To grant the user defined by SID S-1-1-0 Delete and Write DAC permissions to a file, named "Test2", type:

```
icacls test2 /grant *S-1-1-0:(d,wdac)
```